# Custom Ouput of type() in Python

Tags: python, magic-methods

How would I customize the output of a `type()` call against my class?

I am implementing the `__add__` method in my class.  If the user tries to use it incorrectly I'm raising a `TypeError` with the following message:

```
err_msg = "unsupported operand type(s) for -: '{}' and '{}'"
raise TypeError(err_msg.format(type(self), type(other)))
```

The output reads:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '<type 'instance'>' and '<type 'int'>'
```

What would I need to do for it to read `'<type 'my_class'>'` instead?

Comment: What are you trying to add or concatenate?

Comment: The class I'm building is an address book with simple embedded dictionaries.  The purpose of this is for a demonstration.  I've defined "add" to be the union of two address books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to change what `type` returns. You want to make your class a new-style one which (apart from many other advantages) means the string representation of this class object will mention its name, like all proper types (including but not limited to builtins). Change

```
class my_class:
    ...
```

to

```
class my_class(object):
    ...
```

If `my_class` inherits from another class which is old-style itself, make *that* class new-stlye instead.

Comment: I'm writing the code in an IDE using Python 3 and was testing the code through a Python 2 interpreter.  bleh!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is to not use `type()` for my_class, instead use a string:

```
raise TypeError(err_msg.format("<type 'my_class'>", type(other)))
```

Comment: I'm writing this class for demonstration purposes and I need to use the built-in type().  Otherwise this would work just fine.

Comment: You could also do `TypeError(err_msg.format("<type '%s'>" % (self.__class__.__name__), type(other)))`